# how to filter a query based on multiple "or" filters

Tags: c#, linq

I have an enum of Status for an Email entity. I want to refine my query based on a  list of statuses: `List<Status> statuses`. Meaning I want to allow all those statuses, something to the effect of email.Status == 1 || email.Status == 2 ...  How would I accomplish this?

```
foreach (var status in searchOptions.Statuses)
{
   results = results.Where( //what to do here?
}
```

Comment: You can put all your Status' that match your criteria in one list and compare the two lists.

Comment: `result = results.Where(email => email.Status == 1 || email.Status == 2);`

Comment: It depends on exactly what `searchOptions.Statuses` is and if this is EF, but I'd suggest using `Contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var results = table.Where(m => searchOptions.Statues.Contains(m.Status))
```